# Fill color between two series in a LineGraphSeries of Graphview android

Tags: android, android-graphview

I have created a line graph using GraphView demo.But I need to fill the areas only between the lines with a specific colour.
This is what I want to achieve:
[image: img]
Error band for a linegraphseries. or Fill colour between two series in a LineGraphSeries of Graphview.
Can anybody help?